# Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-xxx'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vue.js

Any 3rd party Vue.js library that I try to add to my project, throws the following error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-xxx'
```

I have tried 'vue-treeselect', 'vue-select'*, 'vue-multiselect'* with more or less the same result (* those libraries don't allow `import Modulename from`, but need `const Modulename = require`).

I add those under `"dependencies": {` in `package.json`.

I am using the SPA template for Vue.js provided by dotnet core.

---

Full example with ['tree-select'](https://github.com/riophae/vue-treeselect):

```
import Treeselect from 'vue-treeselect';

/* ... */

value = null;
source = [
    {
        id: 'node-1',
        label: 'Node 1',
        children: [
            {
                id: 'node-1-a',
                label: 'Node 1-A',
            }
      ]
    },
    {
        id: 'node-2',
        label: 'Node 2',
    }
  ];

/* ... */

<treeselect v-model="value"
                :multiple="true"
                :options="source" />
```

Error:

```
in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/components/mycomponent/mycomponent.ts:10:24 
    TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-treeselect'. 'path/to/project/node_modules/vue-treeselect/dist/vue-treeselect.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

---

package.json

```
{
  "name": "MyProject",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "dygraphs": "^2.1.0",
    "ol3-layerswitcher": "^1.1.2",
    "vue-treeselect": "^1.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/dygraphs": "^1.1.6",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.0",
    "@types/vue": "^2.0.0",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "event-source-polyfill": "^0.0.7",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "vue": "^2.5.13",
    "vue-loader": "^14.2.1",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^6.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.13",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2"    
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `package.json`'s `dependencies` object?

Comment: There does not appear to be a definition for that package

Comment: @Phiter I have modified the original post to add `package.json`.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I forgot to mention that: there is no `@types/vue-treeselect` indeed. Although as I understand it [this should not be an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/typescript/issues/3019).

Comment: how to solve this issue If I am not using typescript in vuejs

Answer (score 85):

This error occured because of  `vue-xxxxxx`  has been generated in JavaScript.

***Method 1:***
To avoid the issue I just replace it by the standard **require()**:

```js
const vue-xxxxxx = require('vue-xxxxxx');
// import { vue-xxxxxx } from 'vue-xxxxxx'
```

***Method 2:***
To avoid the issue I just replace these line in the `tsconfig.json`

```
"noImplicitAny": false,
"allowJs": true,
```

***Now  you can use import statement as follows:***

```js
import { vue-xxxxxx } from 'vue-xxxxxx'
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: Upvoting for Method 2

Comment: Searched long for this, thanks you very much! Vote for Method 2

Comment: In my instance I only needed `"noImplicitAny": false` in tsconfig.json file. It solved failing build due to `Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-xxx'`

Comment: In my case, I was getting this error importing one of my own components (`App.vue` by chance), and I had forgotten to mark `lang="ts"` on the `<script setup>`.

Comment: In learning Vue I did some code exercises in JavaScript and put them in a vue file and got a similar error. Didn't like that there was JavaScript. In my case I converted the code to TypeScript and that cleaned it up. Oddly the code worked regardless.

Answer (score 27):

If `@types/vue-treeselect` does not exist then you can manually declare the module using ambient definitions.

Create a `.d.ts` somewhere in your project (warning: it should not use `import` or `export`) and define your module. If you don't want to type-check it (makes everything imported to be infered as `any`) :

```
declare module 'vue-treeselect'
```

If you want to type-check it :

```
declare module 'vue-treeselect' {
  export function something(): void
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Because any of given solutions haven't helped me per se, I had to create a dedicated `vendor.d.ts` (`shims-vue.d.ts` did not work) file in my project root folder, and then put there following line:

```
declare module 'my-module-name-here';
```

[Source](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-third-party-modules-how-to-declare-and-resolve-these-errors/34212/2)

Comment: you need to add `shims-vue.d` to tsconfig.json under `compilerOptions.types` array

Answer (score 5):

In `tsconfig.json` file simply add `"allowJs": true,` solved it for me

Answer (score 4):

It turns out the question was wrong, since I wanted to use '@riophae/vue-treeselect' but I was targeting 'vue-treeselect' instead.

But this was just one part of the problem, it is still not trivial (at least for me) to import 3rd party npm components into a Vue.js typescript project.

This is how I solved it:

---

Quick & dirty solution (when one does not care about the type and just wants to import the library)

**Steps:**

1. Change `tsconfig.json` (the Typescript configuration of your project) to allow `import Treeselect from '@riophae/vue-treeselect';`:

   `"noImplicitAny":  false`

*(without this step you get an error that states: `TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@riophae/vue-treeselect'. 'path/to/project/node_modules/@riophae/vue-treeselect/dist/vue-treeselect.min.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.`)*

2. Import module and register as 'treeselect':

   `import Treeselect from '@riophae/vue-treeselect';`

   `Vue.component('treeselect', Treeselect);`

*(without this step you get an error that states: `Unknown custom element: <treeselect> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`)*

3. Use it in the view:

   `<treeselect v-model="value" :multiple="true" :options="source" />`
4. Rember to set the style at the bottom of the .vue.html page:

   `<style src="@riophae/vue-treeselect/dist/vue-treeselect.min.css"></style>`

---

If you want to do things properly, I highly recommend this article:

**"Write a declaration file for a third-party NPM module"**

https://medium.com/@chris_72272/migrating-to-typescript-write-a-declaration-file-for-a-third-party-npm-module-b1f75808ed2

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vue, let's add as below to `shims-vue.d.ts` file

```
declare module 'module-name-here' {
  import { ModuleNameHere } from 'module-name-here'
  export { ModuleNameHere }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Folder **d** in **src** then create a file `vue-treeselect.ts` and write `declare module 'vue-treeselect';` in file `vue-treeselect.ts`