# How to install V-calendar

Tags: vue.js, vcalendar

I tried to install v-calendar component following the steps in https://vcalendar.io/installation.html

I find the following error near the import statement in main.js

import VCalendar from 'v-calendar'

Could not find a declaration file for module 'v-calendar'. (Added image of the error).[image of the error that i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4tNU.png)

Please help.

Comment: Does your code run, anyway? If it does not, and you already installed the `v-calendar`-package, try installing the types (`npm i -D @types/v-calendar`) as VS Code suggests.

Comment: @STh I have tried that also. Getting only npm error. NO clue what happens.        npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fv-calendar - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@types/v-calendar@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-xxx'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258849/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-vue-xxx)